# How to use kbdd in ubuntu

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

Previously, I posted a question asking for a [command to toggle keyboard layout.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054489/command-to-toggle-keyboard-layout/1054496#1054496) That time, there was given an alternative suggestion and I couldn't get what I exactly wanted. Continuing search on it, I recently found that kbdd daemon coulld do the thing I wanted, but it seemed to me that it has something to do with the window manager, i.e. GNOME Shell.

I tried the following commmand in vain.

```
kbdd
dbus-send --dest=ru.gentoo.KbddService /ru/gentoo/KbddService ru.gentoo.kbdd.set_layout uint32:1
```

Could you walk me through the demonstration of kbdd daemon? I want it to toggle keyboard layout per-window.

Comment: `kbdd` isn't specific to Gnome, or any other WM. Rather, it's specific to Xorg. You just run `kbdd`, and it works, i.e. saves keyboard layout per window. That said, it's odd to see `kbdd` used with Gnome, because later has its own settings to enable per-window layout. `kbdd` is typically used with bare WMs, like i3 or Awesome, since these unfortunately come without bells'n'whistles *(but they're still amazing because of tiling)*. The takeaway is, did you try not to use `kbdd`, but simply to enable per-window layout in Gnome settings?

Comment: But then I have to use keyboard shortcut to change keyboard layout. I want it to be a command in a terminal because I want to execute it when I enter/exit vim.

Comment: Ok, what about [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/596/per-window-keyboard-layout/) *(note: I didn't try it)*. It says it allows you to make Gnome to remember a layout for specific application. So you can e.g. run `gvim`, and have the addon to remember the layout for gvim application.

Comment: I've already come up with that idea and I soon realized that I'd rather love to use vim in a pane of tmux. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I found that xdotool can do exactly what I wanted.